# Can the spec_name of the RuntimeVersion be changed on a runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, try-runtime

Can the spec_name of the RuntimeVersion be changed on a runtime upgrade? And if so, can the check performed by the try-runtime cli that the spec_names have to match be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change that field.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/0c5dcca9e3cef6b2f456fccefd9f6c5e43444053/substrate/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1724-L1726